# Why are we getting RemoteCertificateNameMismatch error?

Tags: identityserver4

We are getting RemoteCertificateNameMismatch in our production environment. We have spent quite a bit to time and read up several links and blogs but we are not able to determine the root cause. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

### Steps to replicate

1. We created a code signing certificate on another machine. Exported it out (including private key), using the following powershell command:
   New-SelfsignedCertificate -KeyExportPolicy Exportable -Type CodeSigningCert -DnsName localhost, webapi.mycomp.com, authserver.mycomp.com -Subject "CN=MyWebAPI" -KeySpec Signature -KeyAlgorithm RSA -KeyLength 2048 -HashAlgorithm SHA256 -CertStoreLocation "cert:\LocalMachine\My"
2. We imported it into our prod Server ( Windows 2008 R2)  under Local Computer/Trusted Root. We also copied it to Local Computer/Personal (just in case to see if it helps)
3. IdentityServer4 is running on is running on IIS 7.5 on say prod Server with the following bindings:
   hostname localhost on port https 5001 with our SSL certificate
   hostname authserver.mycomp.com on port https 443 with our valid SSL certificate
   We are making use of client credentials workflow
   We have specified the correct certificate name in Startup.cs:  builder.AddSigningCredential("CN=MyWebAPI");
   The .well-known/openid-configuration shows the correct info.
4. Web API is running on IIS 7.5 on the same Server with the following bindings
   hostname webapi.mycomp.com on port https 443 with our SSL certificate
   In the Web API solution, for Bearer Token authentication, AuthorityURL is set to https://localhost:5001/
5. We are able to connect to token endpoint https://authserver.mycomp.com/connect/token and successfully get an access token (by passing in the correct grant type, client id, client secret and scope). This access token is valid (we verified it in jwt.io)
6. However when we make a call to the webapi at https://webapi.mycomp.com
   via swagger in Chrome, (after specifying the access token after clicking the Authorize button): it prompts for user id & password when we click on the Execute button
   via postman (after specifying the access token the Bearer Token in Authorization tab): we get 401 unauthorized error

In both cases, we see the following exception in our stdout log:
IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: '[PII is hidden. For more details, see https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/PII.]'.
System.InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: '[PII is hidden. For more details, see https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/PII.]'.
---> System.IO.IOException: IDX20804: Unable to retrieve document from: '[PII is hidden. For more details, see https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/PII.]'.
---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure: RemoteCertificateNameMismatch
at System.Net.Security.SslStream.SendAuthResetSignal(ProtocolToken message, ExceptionDispatchInfo exception)
at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ForceAuthenticationAsync[TIOAdapter](TIOAdapter adapter, Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] reAuthenticationData, Boolean isApm)
at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsyncCore(Boolean async, Stream stream, SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

Comment: A common problem is that when the client wants to talk to the IdentityServer, it can't use the public HTTPS name due to networking issues, instead you need to talk to IDentityServer using its "local network name". You can set that with the  OpenIdConnectOptions.MetadataAddress property.

Comment: As mentioned under item 4 above, we have set AuthorityURL is set to https://localhost:5001/ . So it is not a public Https. So I am not able to understand your suggestion. Could you please elaborate.

Comment: The error you get is that the Client&API can't make a HTTPS connection to IdentityServer. you can use options.MetadataAddress to use HTTP internally behind the server firewall and then use HTTPS as the authority.

Comment: Sorry it is still clear.

1) Are you suggesting that we set the following options:
options.Authority = "https://localhost:5001";
options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
options.MetadataAddress = "http://localhost:5001/.well-known/openid-configuration";


2) Should I leave the binding in applicationHost.config for my authserver as is, i.e.
  <bindings>
   <binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:5001:localhost" />
            <binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:443:authserver.mycomp.com" />
        </bindings>

Comment: 5001 i usually HTTPS, you need to use HTTP internally, like port 5000. or use a separate cert locally. The problem is that internal services can't reach the public IP that the domain name points to. see the answer here  https://superuser.com/questions/139123/why-cant-i-access-my-own-web-server-from-my-local-network